# What simple coupling argument might be meant here?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

First some preliminaries.

Let $B_L=\left\{0,1,\ldots,L-1\right\}^d,~d\geq 2, L\geq 3$. Moreover, $X=\left\{0,1,2\right\}$ and $X^{B_L}=\left\{x\colon B_L\to X\right\}$. Let $\delta_L\in (0,1)$. By $\mathcal{B}$ denote the Borel-$\sigma$-Algebra on $X^{B_L}$ which is generated by the cylindersets $C(y_{i}^{i+n})=\left\{x\in X^{B_L}: x_i=y_i,x_{i+1}=y_{i+1},\ldots,x_{i+n}=y_{i+n}\right\}$. Last but not least, let $P_L$ be a product measure on $X^{B_L}$ defined by
$$
P_L(C(y_{i}^{i+n}))=\prod_{k=i}^{i+n}p(y_k).
$$
Set $p(0)=1-2\delta_L, p(1)=p(2)=\delta_L$.

---

Now suppose that $\lim_{L\to\infty}\delta_L=0$ and $\lim_{L\to\infty}\delta_LL^{d/2}=\infty$. Consider $\delta_L^3L^d$. Because $\delta_L^3L^d>0$ there are two cases:

Case 1: $\lim_{L\to\infty}\delta_L^3L^d=0$

Cse 2: $\limsup_{L\to\infty}\delta_L^3L^d>0$.

If case 1, suppose that
$$
\lim_{L\to\infty}P_L(E)=1,
$$
where $E$ is the event two have an adjacent 1,2-pair.

Now to my question:

> > It is said, that in case 2 one can show $P_L(E)\to 1$ as $L\to\infty$ by using a very simple coupling argument, using case 1. How might this be meant?

I thought about that but did not come to an idea, unfortunately.
Although the needed coupling argument is described to be *very simple*, I do not understand what might be meant.

Mayber anybody can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick $\delta_L$ satisfying case (1) and $\delta_L'$ satisfying case (2). Since by definition $\delta_L' >\delta_L$ for large enough $L$, $p'(0):= 1-2\delta_L' < p(0) : = 1-2\delta_L$ and $p'(1)=p'(2) : = \delta_L' > \delta_L = p(1)=p(2)$ for large enough $L$. Thus we can find a monotone coupling as follows.

Define a Uniform $(0,1)$ variable $U(v)$ on each vertex  $v$ independently of each other. For case (1), define $X(v)$ to be $1$ if $U(v) \in (0,\delta_L)$, $X(v)$ to be $2$ of $U(v) \in (1-\delta_L,1)$ and $X(v)$ to be $0$ otherwise.

For case (2), define $X'(v)$ to be $1$ if $U(v) \in (0,\delta_L')$, $X'(v)$ to be $2$ of $U(v) \in (1-\delta_L',1)$ and $X'(v)$ to be $0$ otherwise.

To be more precise, for every vertex $v$ we have the measure space $([0,1]^2, \mathcal B [0,1]^2, \mu)$ where $\mu$ is the measure supported on the diagonal of $[0,1]^2$ with $\mu (\text{segment joining $(x,x)$ and $(y,y)$}) = |x-y|$. Call the segment joining $(x,x)$ and $(y,y)$ to be $s(x,y)$. Define $(X(v),X'(v))$ on the diagonal of $[0,1]^2$ (at other places it does'nt matter what you define) as follows. $(X(v),X'(v)) = (1,1)$ on $s(0,\delta_L)$, $(X(v),X'(v)) = (0,1)$ on $s(\delta_L,\delta_L')$, $(X(v),X'(v)) = (2,2)$ on $s(1-\delta_L,1)$, $(X(v),X'(v)) = (0,2)$ on $s(1-\delta_L',1-\delta_L)$, $(X(v),X'(v)) = (0,0)$ otherwise.

Clearly $X$ and $X'$ have the right distribution. Further for every realization, if we have an adjacent $1,2$ pair for $X$ then we must have an adjacent $1,2$ pair for $X'$ for large enough $L$ by the coupling. So we are done.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19905/discussion-on-answer-by-gmath-what-simple-coupling-argument-might-be-meant-here). You will find your whole discussion has been saved up there, so don't panic. =)

Comment: @gmath I think the following is unclear to me: You show that if the probability for a 1 and a two is larger in the second case that it is more likely that an adjacent (1,2)-pair exists than in the first case. My problem is: I do not see how THIS then transfers to the measures $P_L$ resp. $P_L'$.